# AWS API Gateway with both Request Validation and Binary Media Types

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I currently have an API Gateway in AWS that has binary endpoints (i.e. returning application/pdf) and JSON ones with proxy integrations for Lambda functions.

We also setup request validators in the API Gateway, however these don't execute on the JSON endpoints after enabling Binary Media Types in AWS for `*/*`.

Log examples - here with no Binary Media Types, the request validators run and error out correctly

```
Starting execution for request: 98e30d98-8fed-xxxx-xxxx-24be77219c10
HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /api/v1/test
Method request path: {}
Method request query string: {}
Method request headers: {Authorization=...., Accept=*/*, User-Agent=...., X-Forwarded-Proto=https, X-Forwarded-For=..., Host=..., Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, X-Forwarded-Port=443, X-Amzn-Trace-Id [TRUNCATED]
Method request body before transformations: { "fake-data": 2, [TRUNCATED]
Request body does not match model schema for content type application/json: [numeric instance is lower than the required minimum (minimum: 20, found: 2), format attribute "int32" not supported]
Gateway response type: BAD_REQUEST_BODY with status code: 400
```

When I then simply enable Binary Media Types with `*/*`

```
Starting execution for request: 94265e79-4d1a-403a-af74-3d3e65e04ae4
HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /api/v1/test
Method request path: {}
Method request query string: {}
Method request headers: {Authorization=...., Accept=*/*, User-Agent=...., X-Forwarded-Proto=https, X-Forwarded-For=...., Host=..., Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, X-Forwarded-Port=443, X-Amzn-Trace-Id [TRUNCATED]
Method request body before transformations: [Binary Data]
Request validation succeeded for content type application/json
Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxx:function:xxxxxx:current/invocations
```

Clearly the method request body is a [Binary Data], but it does also say `Request validation succeeded for content type application/json`.

Is this capability not supported in AWS - i.e. once we need to support binary media types, request validators can no longer be used?  Unfortunately there's no way to constrain the Accept request header on our end.